# MYSQLi query not updating

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to update a field in my database but nothing happens. I think there might be a possible syntax error but I can't find it! Any help would be much appreciated.

CODE

```
$session = $_SESSION['session'];

$add_data = array(
      'user_id'         => $session_user_id,
      'item_title'      => $_POST['item_title'],
      'product_type'    => $_POST['product_type'],
      'size'            => $_POST['size'],
      'condition'       => $_POST['condition'],
      'duration'        => $_POST['duration'],
      'dispatch'        => $_POST['price'],
      'paypal_email'    => $_POST['paypal_email'],
      'description'     => $_POST['description'],
    );
array_walk($add_data, 'array_sanitize');
$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($add_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $add_data) . '\'';


mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `temp` SET ($fields) VALUES ($data) WHERE session = $session AND user_id = '$session_user_id'");
```

Comment: `session = '$session'` instead of `session = $session`

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand the idea behind prepared statements as offered by the mysqli extension. Please read through the documentation and the millions of examples, since your code currently is wide open to sql injection attacs.

Comment: if user_id datatype is int then write user_id = $session_user_id !!!! Share Structure of your table also